# 405 Method Not Allowed http method being used: Request method 'GET' not supported` in spring-security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the file spring-security.xml configured as follow:

```
    <http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome" 
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>
```

dispatch-servlet.xml as follow

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="springmvc.web" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"  location="/resources/" />

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<!-- Declare a view resolver -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

so accessing through the URL ../myapp/welcome or ../myapp/login I get an 405, and there is a login.jsp under /WEB-INF/view/login.jsp

Thanks

Comment: Show us the handler you expect to handle a request to `/myapp/welcome` or `/myapp/login`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `/login` and `/welcome` are expected to be controller(@Controller annotated classes) methods annotated with appropriate `@RequestMapping`.

One workaround, if all your controller does is to return the view name may be to do the following:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/login" view-name="login"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/welcome" view-name="welcome"/>
```